# How to create custom theme for Google Form?

Tags: html, css, iframe, google-forms

I wanted an embed Google Form in my website so i grabbed embed code and pasted it in my page.

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1u1NO8u4vu6Q9XuUNigo4qy22hjvRmL-HFIRVsgiaL9c/viewform?embedded=true" width="760" height="500" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">Loading...</iframe>
```

(that's what Google gave me)

Everything is working fine BUT it's an iframe so I can't edit it's appearance using CSS. Google Docs' deafult themes don't match my site so I want to this page's CSS. I tried downloading https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1u1NO8u4vu6Q9XuUNigo4qy22hjvRmL-HFIRVsgiaL9c/viewform as html but this way I didn't get the css file. Do I have to create it by myself or there's another solution to my problem?

Comment: I don't know if there's a way to directly access it and actually embed a stylesheet or inline css but you could get crafty. Have you tried actually grabbing your generated form and styling it seperately? http://jsfiddle.net/2kaocfqy/

Comment: The only downside of this is that it loses it's dynamic luster and you'll have to update it manually if you update the actual google form.

Comment: @Evan it should work but I am afraid that my html/css skill is too low to make the messages like "please type in correct url adress" displaying only when I need them :(

Comment: There is a script here that lets you edit the Google Forms CSS by fetching the HTML content, and writing directly onto your page: http://googleformrestyler.apixml.net/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply copy the form section of the html and copy paste to your page. It will post to google, and you still have full control over it.

You can't style it while it's an iframe.

see here for more tips about this:
http://morning.am/tutorials/how-to-style-google-forms/

Comment: It seems great but the problem is that I can't control comments like "invalid email adress" or "this is a required question".

Comment: @StefanRadziuk yes, you have to take care of validation and javascript by yourself, as explained in the article i linked to

Comment: This apply for the "old" Google Forms but not for the "new" ones.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `<form>` tag instead of embedding Google form. This is because the style from embedded form may not match your website scheme.
Here is how you can do it.

1. Create a Google Form.
2. Get the link and open the form in a new tab.
3. Create a barebone form having same items as the Google form.
4. Inspect Google form for `action` attribute.

   4. a. Copy the same action to your form.
5. Inspect and find values for attributes `name` in the Google form.

   5. a. Give the same name values for your form items as well. The values look like `entry.742532386`.
6. Check if your form gets the responses.

**Read more [here](https://blog.webjeda.com/google-form-customize/)**