# Is there a way to edit css of new google forms?

Tags: css, google-forms

Before I used to be able to just copy the source code of the form and paste the part between `<form></form>` into the page and add my own styling. But this doesn't seem to work anymore.
Has anyone found a way to still be able to customize google forms?

Comment: If its not in an iframe then you should be able to change it with CSS

Comment: I can change the css but the form doesn't function anymore

Comment: http://morning.am/tutorials/how-to-style-google-forms/

Comment: Well you need to provide a version of the code and say what you are trying to change

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create custom theme for Google Form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25462740/how-to-create-custom-theme-for-google-form)

Comment: Styling the form and changing the theme of the from are not the same thing AniMenon

Comment: Similar question on [webapps.se]: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/92082/88163

Answer (score 25):

Yes, you can easily make the `<form>` work by following these steps.

1. Create a Google Form.
2. Get the link and open the form in a new tab.
3. Create a barebone form having same items as the Google form.
4. Inspect Google form for `action` attribute.

   4. a. Copy the same action to your form.
5. Inspect and find values for attributes `name` in the Google form.

   5. a. Give the same name values for your form items as well. The values look like `entry.742532386`.
6. Check if your form gets the responses.

Since it is a native `<form>` element, apply CSS however you want to.

**Read more [here](https://blog.webjeda.com/google-form-customize/)**

Comment: For me it works only after disabling limit of answers per a signed person.

Answer (score 3):

Google forms does not currently (mar-2021) have a built in feature to add css or javascript to their forms.

I created this GitHub project to work around the problem: https://github.com/calledit/google_form_javascript_css

Comment: Can't seem to open the serverless site, mate

Comment: I removed the hosting of the serverless site due to complaints.

Comment: Fantastic, this is exactly what I needed! :)

Comment: Actually, I found that this makes Forms unusable as of now. Filed an issue on the Github. :)