# How to organize a long dropdown menu in Google Forms into submenus by alphabet (A-D, E-H, etc.)

Tags: google-forms

I am using Google Forms.  5 questions within the Google Form use the dropdown question type, and there are more than 160 answer options within each of the five dropdowns.  This is really not user-friendly.  I'd like to be able to organize the dropdowns with tabs by alphabet (A-D, E-H, etc.) so it's less visually overwhelming to the user.

I'm just getting started on this problem.  There are no Forms add-ons that would solve this issue.  I know I need to write code for the 5 items, but this is not my strongest area.

Answer (score 0):

Google Forms doesn't include a way to do this. I think that your best bet is to build a form by your own i.e. by using Google Apps Script's HTML Service.

If you do a search it's very likely that you will found some hacks like copying the source code of the respondent view of a Google Form. That was easier on old Google Forms that were based on pretty basic HTML and JavaScript. Nowadays it's a lot harder to do something like that because the source code (HTML/CSS/JavaScript) is being generated by other code.

Related Q&A

- [Is there a way to edit css of new google forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37184582/1595451)

Reference

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm a bit late, but the way I found to get over this was by creating first group of answers that led to 5 other second groups of answers. Make one section containing the first 5 possible questions, than make other 5 sections to re-direct depending on wich section the person answering chooses.

Example:
Section 1 (make it a one answer only single column multiple choice type)

1. What time is it?
   a) 7am (make it lead to Section 2 if marked)
   b) 8am (make it lead to Section 3 if marked)
   c) 9am (make it lead to Section 4 if marked)
   d) 10am (make it lead to Section 5 if marked)
   e) 11am (make it lead to Section 6 if marked)

Section 2 (make it a dropdown type)
2.a) And how many minutes?
a) 7:01
b) 7:02
c) 7:03
etc etc

Section 3 (make it a dropdown type)
2.b) And how many minutes?
a) 8:01
b) 8:02
c) 8:03
etc etc

And keep up until you are done with all the sections. It's overwhelming for you, but as you said, you only cared about how it would be for the ones answering it, and I guess you are right about it.