# Custom Google Form? Example of Google Form API?

Tags: css, google-apps-script, google-api, google-apps, google-forms

I'm trying to make a google form look like my own site. I found examples of how to do this on [How to style Google Forms](http://morning.am/tutorials/how-to-style-google-forms/) and [google-custom-form](https://github.com/heaversm/google-custom-form) (GitHub project), but I tried both of the examples they give and they seem to fail now.

I had a look at [Class Form - Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form) which seems to be like an API, but I can't get my head around the documentation. Does anyone have an example of it working. Or has found another way of getting this to work? It would be really handy to do as embedded forms look really out of sync with the rest of the site.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25462740/how-to-create-custom-theme-for-google-form

Answer (score 1):

The API you're linking to is an apps script API. This is needed if you want to create dynamic forms (dynamic amount of questions, dynamic answers,...) but not for custom styling. An intro to appscript can be found on this page: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/

You could just create a form manually on https://www.google.com/forms/about/

You can change the styling and colors in the top-right of the page. When you are ready to embed the form on your own page you have to press "SEND", an select the embed icon <> at the top.

Comment: I got it to work using one of those examples, but it refreshes the page to the google response which is annoying! Thanks for the answer

Answer (score -1):

I've worked with this a ton, and still have issues with it.  Been learning the new api v4 for sheets but still having trouble, it is still in beta too.  For now I can recommend this solution though by heaversm on github.

https://github.com/heaversm/google-custom-form

The example fully works as long as you find the entry.xxxxxxx for each field and replace in the appropriate js.  To avoid the embed issues, give your form submit on a click function that has the event as the input and then preventDefault on the event like so:

```
$('#submit-button').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    // continue code from heaversm
});
```

Hope this works for you.  Cheers